# Why are my mongodb indexes so large

Tags: mongodb

I have 57M documents in my mongodb collection, which is 19G of data.
My indexes are taking up 10G. Does this sound normal or could I be doing something very wrong! My primary key is 2G.

```
{
        "ns" : "myDatabase.logs",
        "count" : 56795183,
        "size" : 19995518140,
        "avgObjSize" : 352.0636272974065,
        "storageSize" : 21217578928,
        "numExtents" : 39,
        "nindexes" : 4,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "flags" : 1,
        "totalIndexSize" : 10753999088,
        "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 2330814080,
            "type_1_playerId_1" : 2999537296,
            "type_1_time_-1" : 2344582464,
            "type_1_tableId_1" : 3079065248
        },
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

Comment: Which version are you using ? If old one, you may upgrade to use new index, they are smaller. BTW, if the index on _id is 2G, depending of data inside your fields, but for a two fields index it seems ok.

Comment: @AurelienB, the version is 2.0.3

Comment: That's a recent one. Except if the base come from an old one, it should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index size is determined by the number of documents being indexed, as well as the size of the key (compound keys store more information and will be larger). In this case, the _id index divided by the number of documents is 40 bytes, which seems relatively reasonable.

If you run db.collection.getIndexes(), you can find the index version.  If {v : 0}, the index was created prior to mongo 2.0, in which case you should upgrade to {v:1}.  This process is documented here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Index+Versions